# Parameters affecting high-speed PCB transmission line design

Tags: pcb-design, transmission-line

I am designing an I/O board for an NVIDIA Jetson Nano SOM module. The board contains the HDMI, USB2.0, CSI, SD card and power system and GPIOs.

As I am beginner with high-speed designs, I have a problem, please help me to understand.

So for USB 2.0 90 ohm impedance is required, so I calculated the following:

[image: PCB transmission line calculation screenshot]

There I have selected 1 oz copper thickness and FR4 material. My PCB manufacturer has a capability of minimum 0.15 mm spacing and 0.15 mm track width. So after entering all the details, I got 0.77 mm as track width and 0.15 mm as track spacing.

For my reference I have downloaded the official Rpi CM4 IO board Kicad files, which are using 0.15 mm as width and 0.25 mm as gap. I have verified the copper core thickness is 1 oz.

So could you please help me to understand, what's the parameter which is causing the difference in width and gap?

Comment: You're using a two layer board so the traces have to be very wide. On a 4 layer they'd be much smaller due to the extra ground plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is the `H` value. 60 mil is 1.524 mm, which suggests you are using a standard 2 layer board. For high speed interfaces like the ones you mention, you should use a 4 layer board. That way the reference plane is much closer, so your `H` value will be smaller. Here's JLC's standard 4 layer dimensions:

[image]

And here's their 2 layer:

[image]

In the 4 layer stack, the `Prepreg` value corresponds to `H` in your software. In the 2 layer stack, the `Core` value corresponds to `H`. Try experimenting with the values there, and you'll come closer to the values you've observed on the CM4 carrier board.

Comment: So how can I use this tool to calculate the W and S for 4 layer board ??

Comment: Just copy the relevant values your PCB manufacturer provides about their stackup. For example, for the 4 layer one I've linked, you'd set `H = 0.18 mm`, `T = 0.035 mm`. I can't see what `H_t` is on your software's graphic, but cross reference it like the ones I've shown.

Comment: I received the following stackup details from the manufacture. [link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Uyw914f4a4MwZqmK7). And after putting the prepreg value in "H" get impedance different. Please help what I am doing wrong

Comment: @Abhishekbhatia Note in your link that they are quoting the `Single` impedance, not differential. Your \$Z_O\$ looks wrong, Saturn PCB Design (and some others online) give a value close to the manufacturer's value.

Comment: Hope by using this stackup details,I can calculate S and W itself from tool and W=17.5 mil and  S=5 mils ryt ?

Comment: @Abhishekbhatia \$Z_\mathrm{diff}\$ seems a bit low, but you're getting there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123869/discussion-between-abhishek-bhatia-and-awjlogan).